# Installing PostgreSQL 9.6 on RHEL 7.1 requires libsystemd.so

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, postgresql, systemd

When installing PostgreSQL 9.6.0 on RHEL 7.1 using the official [PostgreSQL Development Group](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg96) yum repo, the installation fails, reporting that `libsystemd.so` is needed but not installed:

```
user@host ~ $ sudo yum install postgresql96 postgresql96-devel postgresql96-server
```

Results in:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager, versionlock
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
pgdg96                                                                                                                                                                             | 4.1 kB  00:00:00     
Package postgresql96-9.6.0-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql96-devel.x86_64 0:9.6.0-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
---> Package postgresql96-server.x86_64 0:9.6.0-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: postgresql96-server-9.6.0-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: postgresql96-server-9.6.0-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: postgresql96-server-9.6.0-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: postgresql96-server-9.6.0-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Shouldn't I already have `libsystemd.so` being on RHEL 7.x?

Comment: What version of systemd-libs package do you have?

Comment: Appears to be 208-20.el7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need version 209 at least of systemd-libs. I think that comes with Red Hat 7.2 only.